# Unable to catch 404 error on HttpWebRequest response

Tags: vb.net

Trying the below code to catch 404 error page but seems not to work, I mean 404 error doesn't display in response. The response only displays if the file exists (200 http code) !!  but if the file doesn't exist (404) like in the below example, not msgbox displays, and the exception also doesn't display anything that's why I insert a msgbox in there.

If you try to take out these "111" from the "index.html" and run it, it'll display 200 http code well.

Using VS 2013, don't know, if it's a bug, or because I'm going through a proxy.

Will check it later from home for proxy as at work we're using proxy server.

Can anybody help !!

```
Try
    Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/index111.html")
    Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse

    If response.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        MsgBox("File exist on Server")
        MsgBox(response.StatusCode) '200 HTTP CODE

    'Trying to catch 404 error here
    ElseIf response.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then
        MsgBox("FILE NOT FOUND ON THE SERVER")
        MsgBox(response.StatusCode)
    Else
        MsgBox("NO FILE on the server")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception

      'Msgbox("Error")

End Try
```

Comment: Did you debug the code and see what response code you are getting with the invalid url?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya That is the entire question. OP can't get that status code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.GetResponse` will throw an exception when the request fails, for whatever reason.

There is a `Response` object in the exception through, on which you can ask what the status code was. Check `ex.Response.StatusCode` in your `Catch` block.

Comment: I just used (ex.Message) as **ex.Response.StatusCode** throws "Response is not a member of System.Exception.

Comment: How is that possible? My answer was posted long before yours. See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45521295/timeline

Comment: @alice you need to catch the type `WebException`.